# Does Thanos have the same powers in the MCU as he does in the comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thanos

In the comics, Thanos has powers like energy manipulation, telepathy, flight and magic. In the MCU he is never seen using or having powers without the stones.

Does he have these powers but not use them (preferring to use the stones)? But if so, why not use them in *Avengers: Endgame*?

(I would like to add that I am not asking about Hulk vs Thanos. I'm asking whether he has the above powers beside strength.)

Comment: Does being stronger and tougher than is physically possible count as a power?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did Thanos beat Hulk so easily?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/198503/how-did-thanos-beat-hulk-so-easily)

Comment: Note that the "duplicate" does not discuss any of the listed powers.

Comment: I don't feel like this is a duplicate. He beat Hulk with strength, fighting skill and agility. OP is more interested in other superpowers.

Answer (score 5):

In short, no. Within the MCU Thanos displays a basic understanding of magic but scorns its use. Other than that, he's simply the smartest and most powerful (mutant) scion of a race of metaphorical and literal Titans.

Flight, telepathy and energy manipulation are all skills that he doesn't possess. What he does have in abundance is practically boundless physical strength, rapid healing, nearly invulnerable skin, superior intellect (even for his species) and the strength of will required to handle harness the Infinity Stones.

Note that together those abilities make him an incredibly formidable opponent, but when he's unable to access the Stones, the Avengers and the Guardians end up making pretty short work of him three times.

Comment: Are his physical strength, rapid healing, etc a trait of his species, or could they be construed as some form of super powers? I mean, the Hulk has all of those, but they count as super powers for him.

Comment: @Thunderforge - Are the two mutually exclusive? In DC, for instance, the Martian Manhunter and Superhuman gain their powers from their species. The X-Men, conceived of frequently as a different species, gain their powers from the mutation that differentiates them.

Comment: @Thunderforge - Those appear to be general traits of his species, but amped up to 11 by random mutation.

Comment: About the battle in endgame, they had helping them: the Asgardians, the ravagers, the sorcerers, the wakandans and almost every MCU hero.